# Input keypress enter and go to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I´m trying to do is, if the user press Enter on the keyboard after he has entered text on an input, then it goes to a link.

How would be the best way to do that just for the front end presentation?

this is the html:

```
<form>
     <input class="login_btn" type="text" value="Password" onfocus="this.type='password';this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.type='text';this.value='Password';}"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: your use of `onfocus` and `onblur` is worrying, how about just using `placeholder="Password"` instead? see http://jsfiddle.net/xnjAu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".login_btn").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && this.value.length > 0) { //check for empty input as well
        //Enter was pressed, now do what you need to do.
    }
});
```

BTW: Figuring out if enter has been pressed has been asked many times before. Please consider searching :).